# Realtime Data Updating only on Page Refresh

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs, real-time

I have a realtime chat application using Socket.io built on angular. The problem is my data in the UI is updating only when I refresh the browser instead of being updated constantly.

app.component.ts

```
export class RealtimeSupervisorHeatmapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        callActiveListSubscription: Subscription;
        testLiveData: any;
      constructor(private realtimeSupervisorHeatMapService: RealtimeSocketService, private common: CommonService, private renderer: Renderer2) {
                let token = this.common.session_data["token"];
                this.realtimeSupervisorHeatMapService.initializeConnection(token);
         }

         ngOnInit(): void {
            this.callActiveListSubscription=this.realtimeSupervisorHeatMapService.getLiveCallList().subscribe((data: any) => {
                        console.log('inside get live call list subscription',data); 
                       this.testLiveData = data.list_Of_contacts.length
});
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable, fromEvent, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RealtimeSocketService {
  private socket: Socket;
  private apiUrl = 'http://x.x.x.x:x/x';
  private token;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    
  }

  public initializeConnection(token: string) {
    this.token = token;
    this.socket = io("http://x.x.x.x",{
        query: {
          token: token,
        }
      }
     );

    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket connected');
    });
    this.socket.on('disconnect', (reason: string) => {
      console.log('Socket disconnected:', reason);
    });
  }

  public getLiveCallList() {
    return this.createObservable('streamArray');
  }
 private createObservable(eventName: string){
    return fromEvent(this.socket, eventName);
  }
  public disconnect(){
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Below is my console.log statement from the first time UI is rendered.
{stream: Array(16), list_Of_contact: Array(16)}

I am just rendering {{testLiveData}} in my html file, which i believe is not changing since data is not being updated.

I have tried using behavior subject as below in my service file:

```
private liveCallListSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
public liveCallList$ = this.liveCallListSubject.asObservable();
this.socket.on('streamArray', (data: any) => {
      this.liveCallListSubject.next(data);
    });
this.callActiveListSubscription = this.realtimeSupervisorHeatMapService.liveCallList$.subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('Real-time data received:', data);
      this.testLiveData = data.list_Of_contacts.length;
    });
  }
```

But to no help getting the same result. Any help would be highly appreciated and I am fairly new to socket.

Comment: This feels like an issue with your server.  Can you confirm that get multiple emissions if you do the following in the RealTimeSocketService?`this.socket.on('streamArray', (data: any) => console.log(data));`

Comment: As you are subscribing to n function (getLiveCallList) which returns observable. It should emit the data time to time. If it is not happening, please check your observable.